# How did the T-duality change the dimension of the $D$-brane?

Tags: string-theory, spacetime-dimensions, duality

Quote Clifford Johnson $D$-brane page 125

> Observe that, since T-duality interchanges Neumann and Dirichlet boundary conditions, a further T-duality in a direction tangent to a $Dp$-brane reduces it to a $D(p − 1)$-brane, while a T-duality in a direction
> orthogonal turns it into a $D(p + 1)$-brane.

Could you show a bit math of how that was possible, please? I thought the T-duality was a symmetric equivalence between the "heavy" and "light" theory, so how could the dimension of the $D$-brane change under the T-duality? Didn't that lead to a different theory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$T$-dualizing a certain direction in the target space changes the Neumann $\leftrightarrow$ Dirichlet boundary conditions of open strings, which is interpreted as the D-brane is filling/tangent $\leftrightarrow$ intersecting that direction, i.e. the D-brane dimension is 1 more $\leftrightarrow$ 1 less, respectively.

Carefully analyzing the string spectrum of momentum & winding modes, gauge fields & brane positions confirm this picture, cf. e.g. Refs. 1-3, where all the math details are displayed.

References:

1. Clifford V. Johnson, *D-branes,* 2003; sections 4.9 + 4.10.
2. Barton Zwiebach, *A first course in String Theory,* 2nd edition, 2009; chapter 18.
3. Joseph Polchinski, *String Theory* Vol. 1, 1998; section 8.6.